# Change clr-dg-placeholder icon or background image

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm using clr-dg-placeholder to set a placeholder in a Clarity Datagrid, but I want to change the background image or icon. 
[image]

Is it possible without css?

Comment: The isn’t a feature that you can declaratively change. However if it’s something you really want to you might be able to use css to override the svg.

Comment: @hippeelee, is it possible replacing it with any clr-icon?

Comment: If I recall it’s hard coded into the component scss and I believe you can override it. Sorry I’m not at my computer today. I’ll take a look to confirm when I get in front of my computer.

Comment: Sorry for weekend question, I'm very enthusiastic with this design system and I'm working now in a personal project. Thanks for your time :D

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: I help you with my crazy minds while Monday coming. I have inspected DOM element and it's a long string one. As you said, is a SVG image, so I think it's possible overriding with a SVG from official resource.

https://imgur.com/TrZWosr

As hardcoded, I will try with :host::ng-deep structural directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to turn off view encapsulation for the component that has a datagrid in it and also needs the override.

import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

Then you can target the `.datagrid-placeholder-image` element directly and override the `background-image` property

```
.datagrid-host .datagrid .datagrid-table .datagrid-placeholder-container .datagrid-placeholder-image{
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height="100px" width="100px">YOUR SVG CODE HERE</svg>');
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v1-0-ltorrv) is a running stackblitz with an override.

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you @hippeelee.